# Getting Started With TreeView

Tags: .net, wpf, treeview

I have a collection that has a collection

In the first row I have two ListViews, where the second is a child of the first.
The first ListView does not present the same information as the second.

I would like to do the same thing in the TreeView and I just cannot figure it out.
From what I can tell all levels of the TreeView must present the same information

What I want is a TreeView to look where the levels are not the same

What I want is where the the second ListView is in the first ListView
Not beside it

If the answer is the I can do this with MVVM then there is another good reason to learn MVVM?

Can I do it without MVVM?

```
<Window x:Class="TreeView.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TreeView"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="lvFamilies" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Information"/>
        <ListView x:Name="lvChildren" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=lvFamilies, Path=SelectedItem.Children}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
        <TreeView x:Name="tvFamilies" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="{x:Type local:iLimitedTreeView}">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="True" Click="CheckBox_Click">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBlock>
                    </CheckBox>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>              
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>

namespace TreeView
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<Family> Families = new List<Family>();
            Families.Add(new Family("uncle enrie", new List<string>() {"cousin sal", "niece all"}));
            Families.Add(new Family("aunt harriet", new List<string>() { "cousin jim", "cousin bob" }));
            Families.Add(new Family("aunt nanacy", new List<string>() { "cousin art", "cousin jhonny", "niece amy", "niece sarah" }));
            lvFamilies.ItemsSource = Families;
            tvFamilies.ItemsSource = Families;
        }

        private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CheckBox_Click");
        }
    }
    public class person : iLimitedTreeView
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public person(string name) { Name = name; }
    }
    public class Family : iLimitedTreeView 
    {
        public string Name { get { return Parent.Name; } }
        public person Parent { get; set; }
        public string Information
        {
            get 
            {
                return Name + " " + Children.Count.ToString(); 
            }
        }
        public List<person> Children { get; set; }
        public Family(string parent, List<string> children)
        {
            Parent = new person(parent);
            Children = new List<person>();
            foreach (string s in children) { Children.Add(new person(s)); }
        }
    }
    public interface iLimitedTreeView
    {
        string Name { get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What constructor are you referring to? The way you create instances of your classes is unrelated to how the TreeView works...

Comment: A good tutorial I'd read previously for Wpf/MVVM/TreeViews was this one by Josh Smith: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode

Comment: That tutorial is good, make sure to take full advantage of bindings and templates and work with your ViewModel. Do not try to handle TreeView events and manipulate elements from code, you'll dig your own grave.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque See the ctor in the public class TreeViewData.  Since it is called by xaml I don't have a way to pass data to the ctor.

Comment: @Chris Unfortunately I am not MVVM.  I understand the value and it is on the short list of things to learn but not where I am today.

Comment: @Blam, you can create the data in the code-behind and assign it to the TreeView's ItemSource; you don't have to do it in XAML.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I am starting to figure that out

Comment: MVVM has changed my life.. seriously..